# Mostrar mensaje de validacion (error error-422-unprocessable-entity)

Tags: laravel

Estoy tratando de validar un formulario de contacto (es decir que envié un email a mi correo electrónico) y para la validación estoy haciendolo directamente en el controlador, el tema es que solamente me muestra los mensajes de la validacion (los errores) en la vista una vez que envio el form y vuelvo a actualizar la pagina, y en la consola veo el mensaje: jquery.js:10099 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/sendMailContact net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Hasta ahora tengo esto en el controlador:

```
public function enviarFormContacto(Request $request){

        //Validamos los campos del formulario
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'nombre' => 'required',
            'fono' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'mensaje' => 'required',
            'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha'
        ]);

        //Si hay errores los enviariamos a la vista
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('/sendMailContact')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }

        //Envio del Correo electronico si se paso la validacion
```

Y en el formulario por ejemplo muestro el error asi (en todos los campos):

```
 <div class="row mb-4">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 form-sm"> <i class="fa fa-user prefix"></i><label for="nombre">Mi nombre es:</label>
                      <input type="text" id="nombre"  name="nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Su Nombre y Apellido">
                      @if ($errors->has('nombre'))
                        <small class="form-text text-danger">
                            {{ $errors->first('nombre') }}
                        </small>
                    @endif
                    </div>
```

Y LA RUTA LA TENGO DEFINIDA ASI:

```
Route::post('/sendMailContact', [ContactoController::class, 'enviarFormContacto'])->name('contacto.send');
```

PD: No estoy utilizando ajax para procesar el formulario...

Saludos a todos

Comment: intenta cambiando la directiva @error por @if($errors->has('nombre')) para la directiva debes hacer un bagError pero es mas largo, prueba con esto a ver si te sale

Comment: tampoco me funciona, en la consola veo el mensaje que tengo en el request, pero no imprime nada en la vista

Comment: Estás enviando por ajax o directamente?

Comment: Por lo que vemos tu peticion es asincrona debes manejar el error desdel catch, coloca el codigo de la llamasa via ajax para ayudarte

Comment: Hola, lo estoy trabajando directamente, sin ajax